# Subscript out of bounds in FNN::knn.reg() when y is a dataframe and k = 2

Tags: r, knn

I am trying to make predictions using `knn.reg()` from the `FNN` package, but I'm encountering an unusual error. When `y` gets passed as a data frame to `knn.reg()` and I try to predict using the 2 nearest neighbors, I get the following error message:

`Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds`

However, when `y` is a data frame and `k` is any number other than 2, the function works. I've figured out that passing `y` as a vector works for `k = 2` (and also produces the same predictions as when `y` is a data frame), but I'm not sure why the error keeps popping for when `y` is a data frame.

Code sample here:

```
x = 1:10
y = 10:1

df = data.frame(x, y)

k1vec = FNN::knn.reg(train = df['x'], test = df['x'], y = df$y, k = 1)$pred
k1df = FNN::knn.reg(train = df['x'], test = df['x'], y = df['y'], k = 1)$pred
identical(k1vec, k1df)
[1] TRUE

k2vec = FNN::knn.reg(train = df['x'], test = df['x'], y = df$y, k = 2)$pred
k2df = FNN::knn.reg(train = df['x'], test = df['x'], y = df['y'], k = 2)$pred
`Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds`

k3vec = FNN::knn.reg(train = df['x'], test = df['x'], y = df$y, k = 3)$pred
k3df = FNN::knn.reg(train = df['x'], test = df['x'], y = df['y'], k = 3)$pred
identical(k3vec, k3df)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: seems to be because when subsetting a matrix/data frame with a two-column matrix, the columns are assumed to be row and column indices. For 1 and >2 column matrices, each of the cells are assumed to be indices (ie, not the combination of the two columns).. that is, seems like a bug to me

Answer (score 1):

@rossdrucker9 I ran into the same error by only when in put knn.reg inside for loop. The error appear on the second loop. I spend half a day on `FNN::knn.reg` to get optimal `k` because I gave me better results than caret's knn. However, knn from caret package gave no out of  bound error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the exact same problem, but I ended up here when searching and trying to resolve. I was using `FNN::knn.reg` and I got the following error message (this is only the start of the error message, not the entire message):

```
r Error: Subscript `Z$nn.index` is a matrix, it must be of type logical.
```

Then I ran:

```
train <- as.data.frame(train)
y <- as.data.frame(y)
```

and then I once again ran `knn.reg`:

```
knn1 <- knn.reg(train, test, y, k = 12)
```

and it worked!

(I tried to comment instead of answer but the system won't allow it).